# jquery slideToggle looped divs independently

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having problems with my slideToggle function in jquery when I use divs created in a loop.
When I press one of the buttons I want it to show the corresponding div instead of all the divs underneath all the buttons.

This is my css:

```
 <style>
   .toggle { display:none;}
   p { width:400px; }
 </style>
```

Here is my loop with button and div

```
<?php 
 include('sql.php');

 $i = 0;
 while ($i < count($rows)) {
 echo "
 <button class='trigger'>
 <table width='100%'>
 <tr>
 <td width='20%'><img src='http://localhost/app-side/Icons/beer_icon.png' /></td>
 <td width='80%'><h2>{$rows[$i]['titel']} </h2></td> 

 </tr>
 </table>
 </button><br>

 <div class='toggle'>

<p>
    {$rows[$i]['info']} 
</p>
 </div>";


 $i++;
 }
 ?>
```

And here is my slideToggle function

```
 <script>


  $('.trigger').click(function(){
  $('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');

  });

 </script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to wrap your entire looping html in a further div, and then amending your jQuery like so:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() { 
    $(this).siblings('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Since the two elements are now grouped inside a common parent, one can find the other using the `siblings`-method. Naturally, you can go about this in hundreds of ways, but this one struck me as the quickest and easiest.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QukC8/

Comment: I've tried this and now the buttons doesn't show any of the divs. It buggles my mind since it seems to work in your example, but when the divs are created in a loop it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: Inspect your generated HTML, and make sure that the generated HTML is equivalent to expectations.

Comment: Okay I took the example from jsfiddle and started over from scratch. It now works as a charm! Thanks alot.